# Why is awakeFromNib called twice from a Cell in a TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to understand why awakeFromNib is being called twice in my code. I currently have a tableview that has a special compressible cell that appears once at the end of the table. The first awakeFromNib is being called when the tableview is scrolled to the special cell at the end (which is fine I believe,as the tableview is reusing cells). However, whenever I tap the cell to expand the cell, the awakeFromNib is being called again.

Could anyone explain to me why awakeFromNib is being called twice? And how I could only make it only be called once?

Thanks

EDIT** Code people have requested

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section >= (NSInteger)[self.trip.destinations count]) {
        GuestCell *cell = (GuestCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:GuestCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell setupCellForGuests:self.trip.guests];
        cell.guestExpanded = NO;
        NSLog(@"RETURNING CELL");
        return cell;
    }

    // For all other sections
    return [self prepareCardCellForIndexPath:indexPath forHeightCalc:NO];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section >= (NSInteger)[self.trip.destinations count]) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be called twice if you're only instantiating one cell, so we need to see what code you have in cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Edit your post to include the code that expands the cell.  How do you make the table view know that the cell should expand?  Is it animated?

Comment: @rdelmar Code posted

Comment: Same question. Method `numberOfRowsInSection` called twice as needed. I have 3 sections and this method called 6 times when app loaded. Of course not only `numberOfRowsInSection` called twice, whole process.

Answer (score 5):

You're animating the reload of the expanding row.  The table view implements this by creating another cell for the same index path, and animating a transition from the old cell to the new cell.  It creates a second instance of your cell prototype, so the second instance also receives the `awakeFromNib` message.  If you log `self`, you'll see that the address is different the second time.

I don't think you can avoid the creation of a second cell instance (and thus a second `awakeFromNib`) unless you get rid of the animation.  Even then I'm not sure it will reuse the old cell.

Answer (score 2):

If the cell with that nib is only one in the table, then my guess is that it has something to do with animations. I didn't check how tableview handles cells during animation, but for tableview header it asks for another instance and then performs animation (for example fade) - so the old instance is faded out and the new is faded in. At least that's what I think has the highest probability, if you are handling cells correctly.